# python - dictionary - update text values of keys - setting an priority (max principle)

Tags: python, dictionary, text, compare, key-value

I have the following strings as values for a dictionary key:

```
["low", "middle", "high", "very high"]
```

These are the options for the dicionary item key 'priority', a sample dict element is:

```
{'name': 'service', 'priority': value}
```

My task is to collect a list of dictionaries with the keys, all differ in the key value 'priority'.

```
my_list = [{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'low'}, {'name': 'service', 'priority': 'high'}]
```

In the end a final dictionary item should exist, that has the highest priority value. It should work like the maximum principle. In this case `{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'high'}` would be the result.

The problem is that the value is a string, not an integer. 
Thanks for all ideas to get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approach with itertools module usage:

```
# Step 0: prepare data

score = ["low", "middle", "high", "very high"]
my_list = [{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'low', 'label1':'text'}, {'name': 'service', 'priority': 'middle', 'label2':'text'}, {'name': 'service_b', 'priority': 'middle'}, {'name': 'service_b', 'priority': 'very high'}]

my_list      # to just show source data in list

Out[1]:   

    [{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'low', 'label1': 'text'},
     {'name': 'service', 'priority': 'middle', 'label2': 'text'},
     {'name': 'service_b', 'priority': 'middle'},
     {'name': 'service_b', 'priority': 'very high'}]

# Step 0.5: convert bytes-string (if it is) to string  
# my_list = [{k:(lambda x: (x.decode() if type(x) == bytes else x))(v) for k,v in i.items()} for i in my_list ]

# Step 1: reorganize "score"-list on most useful way - to dict

score_dic = {i[0]:i[1] for i in list(zip(score, range(len(score))))}
score_dic

Out[2]:
    {'low': 0, 'middle': 1, 'high': 2, 'very high': 3}


# Step 2: get result 

import itertools

[max(list(g), key = lambda b: score_dic[b['priority']]) for k,g in itertools.groupby(my_list, lambda x:x['name'])]

Out[3]:
    [{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'middle', 'label2': 'text'},
     {'name': 'service_b', 'priority': 'very high'}]
```

Comment: Question:  
What if my_list has a length of 1 element, then the code exits :  
{'low': 0}  
    itertools.groupby(list_sb_host_auth, lambda x: x['Name'])]
  File "S:/PycharmProjects/pyodbc/app.py", line 439, in <listcomp>
    max_items = [{'Name': k, 'SbAuth': max(list(g), key=lambda b: score_dic_sb_auth[b['SbAuth']])['SbAuth']} for k, g in
  File "S:/PycharmProjects/pyodbc/CMDB-Applikation-Schutzbedarf.py", line 439, in <lambda>
    max_items = [{'name': k, 'priority': max(list(g), key=lambda b: score_dic[b['priority']])['priority']} for k, g in
KeyError: 'very high'

Comment: right. because you have to have matches keys. So the all values which you have used in "my_list" for describing priority (in my example it has three unique values: low, middle, very high) has to be described in "score" list. As you mention, If you cut "score" to the only one value ("low"), there is a mismatch it with some values in "my_list" priority (line "middle" and "very high")

Comment: It gets the certain value or "priority" from "my_list" (for example "low"), and try to find the appropriate number value for this key in "score"-variable (it "0")

Comment: Thx, i check the length of list before, so code is optimal for me. Tx a lot.

Comment: if the dict item has got 4 elements like  
{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'middle', 'label1': 'text', 'label2': 'text'}  
out[3] has got only the key name and priority.  
How can I extend that?

Comment: it depends on. Does it always has the same keys of dict?

Comment: Take a look. I have updated my code, now it has unify approach about keys

Comment: Cpacibo, Alexey! Perfect job.

Comment: Hello, i have run into a situation with unicode chars in the value of key "name". The grouping does not work with the unicodes.
Please can you give me the to run it with unicode strings?

Comment: Do you have an option for me with the code you gave me? the code is running fine and I do want to use it further. Thx in advance.

Comment: Hello, if i understood your situation correctly, pls find solution in "step 0.5" in code above. just try to put this in your code without comments sign.

Comment: hello, thanks for you answer. I implemented the code in 0.5, but no luck.
Please see my edited list my_list for the special character ( ) that seems to create the problems:  
my_list = [{'name': 'service (W1)', 'priority': 'low', 'label1':'text'}, {'name': 'service (W1)', 'priority': 'middle', 'label2':'text'}, {'name': 'service (W2)', 'priority': 'middle'}, {'name': 'service (W2)', 'priority': 'very high'}]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
priorities = ["low", "middle", "high", "very high"]
items = [{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'high'}, {'name': 'service2', 'priority': 'high'}, {'name': 'service', 'priority': 'very high'}, {'name': 'service2', 'priority': 'very high'}]

max_priority = max(items, key=lambda item: priorities.index(item['priority']))['priority']
max_items = [item for item in items if item['priority'] == max_priority]
print(max_items)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'service', 'priority': 'very high'}, {'name': 'service2', 'priority': 'very high'}]
```

Comment: hello!
my output is reduced on one item, the other are deleted. any idea why?
[{'Name': 'service', 'priority': 'very high'}]

Comment: Hi there. I created a new list with multiple entries for you. Your original list contains just 1 item with priority `very high`.